# Numba in python for faster hashing

Tags: python, hash, numba

I am trying to create a program that is able to create x strings and then hash them with SHA-256. I am doing this in python 3.8.6. My code runs fine on my CPU, but I would love to show the difference of CPU and GPU in terms of speed while doing repetitive tasks.

For now it looks like this:

```
import hashlib
import string
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from numba import jit

#@jit(nopython=True)
def strings(b):
    x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(120))
    return x

@jit(nopython=True)
def hasha(a):
        kette = a
        encoded = kette.encode()
        result = hashlib.sha256(encoded)
        hex = result.hexdigest()
        return hex



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    start_time = time.time()
    c = pool.map(strings, range(0, 100000))
    pool.map(hasha, c)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I found numba and read, that it could compile code to run on the GPU. After trying for a while I cannot come up with code that works with numba for me.
First error I got was: "The use of yield in a closure is unsupported.". I "fixed" that with not compiling the strings() function with numba.

The second error happens in hasha() and looks like this: "Unknown attribute 'encode' of type unicode_type"

My guess is, that numba does not know some of the functions that I am using.

Am I right, or is there also another problem? Does anyone have an idea for a workaround in numba or even anything else, except from numba, that I can show how the nearly same code runs faster on a GPU?
Just for notice, I do not own an nvidia GPU, I use an AMD RX580, so I cannot use anything with Cuda in my understanding.

I also tried to use pyopencl but I am not able to really work with that.

Thank you!
Best regards!

Comment: Numba is not going to improve this, it works on numpy code. The code you have basically calls out to built-in functions anyway

Comment: Even if Numba would support this code, which is not the case, it only supports CUDA which does not work (without very experimental tricks) on AMD GPUs. And even if you had a Nvidia GPU, converting automatically this code run efficiently GPUs is not possible yet with any existing compiler. GPUs works very differently from CPUs and there is no automagical ways to compile a general CPU code to a GPU one. There are no magic wands either. If you still really want to run that on GPUs, then you can use OpenCL (likely in C/C++) and this will probably be very hard to implement a fast GPU code with it.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you have a recommendation for something that helps me accomplish what I am trying to do? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Good to know, I saw something about experimental support for AMD thats why I thought it might work. I am also trying to implement it in OpenCL but as you mentioned it is hard for me and really beyond my understanding. Guess I will put that aside and try to look for time measurements from the web somehow. Thank you! @JérômeRichard